# For a smooth integral curve, $c$, if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \inf} c(t) = p$ does $\lim_{t \rightarrow \inf} c'(t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, smooth-functions

If a smooth integral curve has a limit point $p$ and it takes infinite time to reach that point. Does that imply that its velocity approaches $0$ at that point?

Or in other words,

**Updated based on comment suggestions**

Given a smooth vector field $V: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. And an integral curve $c(t)$ satisfying.

$$c'(t) = V(c(t))$$

Let $p$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then,
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \inf} c(t) = p \implies \lim_{t \rightarrow \inf} c'(t) = 0$$

In otherwords, $p$ must be a singular point of the vector field $V$.

I've struggled to prove this as every proof I have seen requires that the derivative be bounded or uniformly continuous, I believe. We know that $c$ is locally lipschitz and smooth. Is there a proof that follows from those two conditions?

**Update**
I know that the above can be proved by using the machinery of flows, but I was trying to avoid that.

**Edit**
We can also assume that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} c'(t)$ exists, since this is an integral curve of a smooth vector field and it approaches a point on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Smooth already implies locally lipschitz (by the mean-value theorem). In this generality the claim does not hold. Consider $c(t)=t^{-1} \cos(t^3)$, then $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} c(t) =0$, but the limit of the derivative does not even exist. Maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Thanks, @SeverinSchraven. Yes, we can assume that the limit of the derivative exists. I  will add that to the question.

Comment: What does integral curve mean? Are you starting from $c'(t)=f(c(t))$, and "integral curve" mean a solution of this?

Comment: Yes, it is an ODE solution. For background I was trying to prove that an integral curve of a flow couldn't approach another point at infinite time with a finite speed. However, I hoped that I could prove this as a stand alone result.

Comment: @Jeff Can you please add your precise assumptions and your definition of integral curve. The assumption that $c(t)$ solves an ODE is not saying much (it always solves the ODE $c'(t) =f(t)$ with $f(t)=c'(t)$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I've updated the conditions more precisely, in short we have that $c'(t) = V(c(t))$ where V is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point sequence $c(n)$ converges to $c^*$ due to the asymptotic convergence of the function to $c^*$.

$c$ is continuously differentiable. Thus there are middle points $\theta_n\in(n,n+1)$ with $c'(θ_n)=c(n+1)-c(n)$ via the mean value theorem.

Per the first point, $c'(θ_n)$ converges to zero.

$c(θ_n)$ also converges to $c^*$.

Due to the continuity of $V$, $V(c^*)=\lim_{n\to\infty}V(c(θ_n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}c'(θ_n)=0$.

Again by the continuity of $V$, $\lim_{t\to\infty}c'(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}V(c(t))=V(c^*)=0$.

Comment: I don't get the reasoning that $c'(\theta_n) = 0$. I never stated that $V(p)=0$.

Comment: Oh nevermind. Now, I think I see the chain of reasoning. Nice!