# Proving that a limit of the function is a solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation:

$$ y'=y^{5}+y^{55}-2y $$

Assume $ \varphi\left(t\right) $ is a solution on an interval $(a,b) $, such that there exists $t_0 \in (a,b) $ that satisfies $ |\varphi\left(t_{0}\right)|<1 $.

I have to prove that $\varphi$ can be extended to $(a,\infty)$, prove that $\varphi$ has a limit at $\infty$ and find it.

**My work so far**

I proved that $\varphi$ can be extended to $(a,\infty)$. I have proved that under the assumption of existence of $t_0$ such that $|\varphi(t_0)|<1$, for any $t$ we have $|\varphi(t)|<1$ (Since $1,-1,0$ are constant solutions and we have uniqueness).

Now, note that if there exists $t_1 $ such that $\varphi(t_1)>0$ than for any $t $ we have $\varphi(t)>0$ and otherwise $\varphi(t)<0$ for any $t$. So I want to solve for 2 cases which will be the same idea, without loss of generality assume $0<\varphi<1$.

Under this assumption I proved that $\varphi $ is monotone decreasing.

Now all I have left to do is to prove that the constant function $L$ where $L$ is the limit, is also a solution - it will prove that the limit is $0$ as I thought.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416444/for-a-smooth-integral-curve and many other similar questions.